# Get title of current figure in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, properties, title, figure

I have a figure opened with a certain title.
How do I get the title string?

I have tried `get(gcf)` but I don't know how to navigate to the title.

I want to get the title of many figures, add some more characters to the string and write it back.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
x=0:.1:3.14;
plot(sin(x))
title('Sin(x)')

%get the title
h=get(gca,'Title');
t=get(h,'String') %t is now 'Sin(x)'

%new title
new_t=strcat(t,' Sine function')
title(new_t)
```

Comment: You could make it into single line `t =get(get(gca,'Title'), 'String');`

Answer (score 2):

Given a handle to a figure window, this shows how you can "get" and "set" the "title" of the figure.

> Run the following lines of code and see for yourself. I used Matlab 2016a.
>
> Here is a summary:
>
> ```
> h = figure;
> h.Children.Title.String = 'Your desired title';
> disp(['Current Figure Title: ', h.Children.Title.String]);
> figure(h);
> ```

**Create a demo figure with title: 'Test Title-1'**

```
h = figure;
title('Test Title-1');
```

**Access the figure title through the handle: h**

```
figTitle = h.Children.Title.String; 
disp(['Current Figure Title: ',figTitle]);
figure(h);
```

**Change the figure title to something new: 'Test Title-2'**

```
h.Children.Title.String = 'Test Title-2'; 
disp(['New Figure Title:',h.Children.Title.String]); 
figure(h);
```